# Select * with result columns that only contain values

Tags: postgresql, select, filter, distinct

postgresql
--I don't want to have to enter each repeating column, I want syntax in the where clause that checks all the columns and returns only columns with data

```
SELECT *
FROM table_with_200_columns
where datetime between '2021-01-01' and current_date
and column.1 is not null
and column.1 <>''
and column.2 is not null
and column.2 <>''
and column.3-200 is not null
and column.3-200 <>''
;
--something like this with an "presently unknown function" as in the example of 'allofthemtherecolumns'
SELECT *
FROM table_with_200_columns
where datetime between '2021-12-01' and current_date
and allofthemtherecolumns is not null
and allofthemtherecolumns <>''
```

your assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean with "*only columns with data*"? A different number of columns per rows? That's not possible.

Comment: If there are rows in your table in which _all_ columns contain either null or empty string and you want to filter them then it seems that you have to review your data design.

Comment: There are columns that may/may not have a value in each record.  I want to only receive results for columns that the query filters to that contain values. i.e., if the field 'is_closed' and the field either has a value, is null or is blank, I want my query results to eliminate that column from the result set and any other column that doesn't have any values in that column once the query is run.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform a row into an hstore record, then extract just the values and look if none of them is null

```sql
select * from t 
where false = ALL (SELECT unnest(avals(hstore(t))) IS NULL);
```

PS: you would need the hstore extension

Answer (score 0):

Convert the table row to json, remove `datetime` and all null/blank valued key, then check it's not empty:

```
select *
from table_with_200_columns
where datetime between '2021-01-01' and current_date
and regexp_replace(jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(table_with_200_columns) - 'datetime')::text, '"[^"]+":"",?', '', 'g') != '{}'
```